# empty array outside function and array is ok inisde

Tags: php

I'm having problems getting my array values outside a function and from another file.
Inside the array and function i have this, those values are defined with getters and setters

```
Array ( [0] => XXXXXXXXXX [1] => 5ºA )
```

Those values are defined by setters and they working since i have the values with print_r

```
 public function getTurmaeProfessor(){
    global $myArr;
    $myArr[] = $this->getProfessor();
    $myArr[] = $this->getTurma();
    print_r($myArr);
    return $myArr;
}
```

Now from another file i use this

```
$dados = $esmaior->getTurmaeProfessor();
if(!$dados){
    echo "sem dados";
}
print_r($dados);
```

And the result is empty, so the array is empty...why??

Thanks

UPDATE
This function is called here

```
$this->setTurma($nome_turma);
        $this->setProfessor(($nome_professor));
        $this->getTurmaeProfessor();
```

So if a put this

```
public function getTurmaeProfessor(array $myArr)
```

I'm gonna need to change the call method...how to do it??

UPDATE 2

Ok...
Let me put all maybe it's better to understand.
My main function is this one

```
    public function novaAula($atividade, $turmas, $local, $dataAula, $inicio, $fim, $fundamentacao, $observacoes, $id_professor){
    try{
    $stmt = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO `aulas_exterior` (`atividade`,`id_turma`,`local`,`data_aula`,`inicio`,`fim`,`fundamentacao`,`observacoes`) 
                                VALUES (:atividade,:id_turma,:local,:data_aula,:inicio,:fim,:fundamentacao,:observacoes);");
    $stmt->bindparam(":atividade", $atividade);
    $stmt->bindparam(":local", $local);
    $stmt->bindparam(":data_aula", $dataAula);
    $stmt->bindparam(":inicio", $inicio);
    $stmt->bindparam(":fim", $fim);
    $stmt->bindparam(":fundamentacao", $fundamentacao);
    $stmt->bindparam(":observacoes", $observacoes);
    $turma = explode(',', $turmas);
    foreach ($turma as $id_turma) {
        $stmt->bindParam(':id_turma', $id_turma, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $result = $stmt->execute();
        $idAula = $this->db->lastInsertId();
        $this->insertPedidoByLastId($idAula,$id_professor, $id_turma);
        $nome_turma = $this->getTurmaById($id_turma);
        $nome_professor = $this->getNomeById($id_professor);
        $this->setTurma($nome_turma);
        $this->setProfessor(($nome_professor));
        $this->getTurmaeProfessor();
    }
    if (!$result) {
        print_r($stmt->errorInfo());
        return array('status' => 'error', 'message' => 'Problema ao gravar esta nova atividade...');
    }
    else{
        return array('status' => 'success', 'message' => 'O pedido foi criado com sucesso...');
    }
} catch (Exception $ex) {
    echo $ex->getMessage();
    }
}
```

and as you can see i'm setting these 2

```
 $this->setTurma($nome_turma);
        $this->setProfessor(($nome_professor));
```

and finally i call the method

```
$this->getTurmaeProfessor();
```

Entering this function i want to have names from those 2 setters

```
 public function getTurmaeProfessor(array $myArr){
    $myArr[] = $this->getProfessor();
    $myArr[] = $this->getTurma();
    return $myArr;
}
```

Until now...everything is working....the problem is when i'm trying to get the return in other file...i receive empt...why??

Comment: Why are you using global ___and___ returning the value?

Comment: Because i need to return values to my fill my pdf

Comment: That doesn't answer the question.... why are you using __both__? You should be using an argument for the function, and a return, not a global

Comment: check update 2 please

Comment: You need to pass an array as an argument to this function: show how you are calling the function.

Comment: $dados = $esmaior->getTurmaeProfessor();
    if(!$dados){
        echo "sem dados";
    }
    print_r($dados); and i receive Array ( [0] => [1] => ) 0

Answer (score 5):

Do not use `global`. Fix your function to accept arguments:

```
 public function getTurmaeProfessor(array $myArr){
    // remove global $myArr;

    ....

    return $myArr;
}
```

optionally (but I do not recommend it unless you know you want to go that way) pass your array by reference:

```
 public function getTurmaeProfessor(array &$myArr){
    // remove global $myArr;

    // no return this time needed
}
```

Now, since `getTurmaeProfessor()` requires argument you must change all the invocations to do that, i.e.

```
$dados = $esmaior->getTurmaeProfessor($myArr);
```

Comment: Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to ESMAIOR::getTurmaeProfessor() must be of the type array, none given,..$dados = $esmaior->getTurmaeProfessor();

Comment: See edited answer. I also recommend you do some basic tutorials as you lacks fundamentals

Comment: I don't know if you understand my question or if i have explained me well....this is not a lack, if not receiving the return i'm expecting when i call that function. Inside the fucntion the array is correct, outside when called is empty